# 「逝ったぁ」what does mean?

Tags: meaning, words, usage

「逝ったぁ」と友達からかいたが、この言葉は意味がなんですか
How about use it?

Comment: Context? ... 友達なら直接聞きなはれ。。。

Comment: @Chocolate I just saw this when he complained app cant work in roomchat, 直接聞いたらヘンなと思う:D

Comment: ああ。。じゃあ、「壊れた」ってことでしょうね。。。

Comment: 「[逝]{い}った」です。「[逝]{い}く」は、ふつう、「[死]{し}ぬ」って意味です。

Comment: Apologies for bringing the tone down, but this kanji is also used to refer to having an orgasm. Surely not what your colleague intended, but worth bearing in mind to save yourself an embarrassing misuse of this character. It's more common for it to be written in kana in that context, but I have also seen the kanji used too.

Comment: @kandyman I don't think 逝く is commonly used in such a way.

Comment: @naruto I didn't say it was common, but I have seen it used. And it could be embarrassing to use it incorrectly.

Comment: 新しい携帯を買って、それから半年後である今日、また携帯が逝ったぁぁぁぁーーー！（また携帯が壊れて【死んで】しまった！）

Comment: 「逝った」の使う現状は user27280さんに書いてもらったんですよね。
 My colleague tried to build app on server many times, but it was failed, so every time he fixed it, result returns fail , he wrote that :D

Comment: @Earthliŋ おおっすみません_(._.)_ @narutoさんいつもありがとう＾＾

Answer (score 2):

逝く【いく】 is a godan-verb that conjugates in the same way as 行く and means "(for a person) to pass away" or "to die". This is (was?) a relatively rare formal verb used in novels and news headlines, but in the last few decades it's also been used like this, as net-slang. [逝ってよし](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_itteyoshi.htm) is perhaps the best-known example, although this phrase is almost dead now.